# How to have a smooth repositioning of child elements when resizing a container?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Let's say I have a container div with a number of child divs.

The child divs are floated left, so that they form a number of horizontal lines.
When I **progressively** resize the width of the containing div (with `$container.stop().animate()` for example), the child divs are **abruptly** moved to the next lines when the container's width reaches certain thresholds

Is there any technique/plugin out there that would make the re-ordering of the child elements smoother ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I know of a certain plugin that could help you, but if one existed it would probably do the following to animate each of the children into their final positions along with the container animate:

1. Use `css()` to resize the container to the target width.
2. Note the `position()` of each of the container's `children()`.
3. Use `css()` to resize the container back to its original width.
4. Absolutely position each of the `children()` with a `top` and `left` equal to that of their original `position()`s. They shouldn't move at all in this step so test your function up to here to make sure of that.
5. Use `animate()` to animate the width of the container and at the same time use `animate()` to animate the `top` and `left` to the values we got in step 2.
6. In the `animate()` complete callback, change the positioning of the children back to their original values.
7. ???
8. Profit